# dataframe.to_csv with pipe delimiter adding extra columns

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am loading the results of an Oracle query into a dataframe using pd.read_sql and then writing it out to a CSV file using df.to_csv(fileName, sep='|', header=True, index=False).  Even though I am using  the pipe character as a delimiter, columns that contain commas are being spilt as if the commas are the delimiter.  This is causing a misalignment of values in my CSV file. Has anyone else experienced this?  Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output vs. what is desired?  The way I read this, it sounds like the issue is in whatever application you are using to read the CSV, rather than any issues with pandas or the CSV itself.  (Unless you mean that commas in the input are being *replaced* with pipes in the output?)

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.  I have a column with commas in it and when I open the CSV file in a text editor, the commas have been replaced by pipe characters - which pushed other values in that row over several columns.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you confirm that the columns are split correctly before calling `df.to_csv`?

Comment: Yes.  It's really troublesome.  When I print the dataframe it looks fine.  I replaced the commas with semicolons in my SQL statement, loaded the data frame, and saved to CSV and it works as expected.  Then I replaced the semicolons with commas in my dataframe just before writing to CSV and the problem returned.

Comment: Can you show some code to reproduce this? Preferably without the Oracle part, because I don't see what this has to do with the problem.